# Razor Page throws error whenever change is made to cshtml without rebuilding the project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, roslyn, razor-pages

Probably because I updated my .NET Core to latest 2.1 recently. Now in a Razor page project of mine, whenever I change the `.cshtml` content, the following error shows up:

[image]

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   process this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately. Generated Code
>
> The type 'RazorInjectAttribute' exists in both
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor,
>   Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>   +
>           [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
>   The type 'RazorInjectAttribute' exists in both
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor,
>   Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>   +
>           [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
>   The type 'RazorInjectAttribute' exists in both
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor,
>   Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>   +
>           [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
>   The type 'RazorInjectAttribute' exists in both
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor,
>   Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>   +
>           [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
>   The type 'RazorInjectAttribute' exists in both
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor,
>   Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>   +
>           [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]

The error goes away when I perform a build (Ctrl Shift B). This is very annoying. Anyone knows a fix for it?

Comment: Check your references. It is still referencing the previous versions of the listed dependencies ie *Version=2.1.0.0*. They were not removed during the update to *Version=2.1.1*..

Comment: @Nkosi I checked (did you mean Nuget btw?). The problem is it is blocked and say Blocked by Project and I cannot change anything. How can I update them?